# Is there a way to store date and time in a struct? C++

Tags: c++, date, time, struct

I need to store current date and time on a string to store it in a struct. I don't even know if that's possible, but I need to do it. I will try to further explain it:

I have this struct:

```
struct Apartment{
int number;
string owner;
string condition;
}ap
```

And this code to add a new object of the same struct:

```
cout << "Enter the apartment number: " << endl;
cin >> ap.number;
cout << "Enter the name of the owner: " << endl;
cin >> ap.owner;
cout << "Enter the condition: " << endl;
cin >> ap.condition;
```

And I need a variable for date and time. I need it to save the time and date the object was created. I don't know if I can do it with string or any other thing. I need it to be printable, too. I would be really thankful if you could help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [std::time_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t), [std::time()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) and [std::ctime()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/ctime) like this:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Apartment
{
    int number;
    std::string owner;
    std::string condition;
    std::time_t when;
};

int main()
{
    Apartment ap;

    std::cout << "Enter the apartment number: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> ap.number;

    std::cout << "Enter the name of the owner: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> ap.owner;

    std::cout << "Enter the condition: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> ap.condition;

    ap.when = std::time(0);// set the time to now

    std::cout << "Record created on: " << std::ctime(&ap.when) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The std::tm structure (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm), std::localtime and std::gmtime functions will also be helpful in case of decoding and splitting the time_t into parts, available to be printed.